# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for @org_ca = update_person_params["org_contacts_attributes"]["0"]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I just learn ruby on rails from youtube and tried to follow this, and I got an error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for @org_ca = update_person_params["org_contacts_attributes"]["0"]

and this is the code for org_people_controller.rb

```
def edit
    @person = OrgPerson.find(params[:id])
    @contactInfo = OrgContact.find_or_initialize_by(org_person_id: params[:id])
    @contactInfo[:email] = current_org_person.email
    @person.org_contacts.build(@contactInfo.attributes)
end

def update

    # Create org_ca to sanitize our hash to proper "contacts" attributes
    @org_ca = update_person_params["org_contacts_attributes"]["0"]
    @org_ca[:typ_country_id] = @org_ca.delete :typ_countries
    @org_ca[:typ_country_id] = @org_ca[:typ_country_id][:id]
    @org_ca[:typ_region_id] = @org_ca.delete :typ_regions
    @org_ca[:typ_region_id] = @org_ca[:typ_region_id][:id]
    @org_ca[:org_company_id] = @org_ca.delete :org_company
    @org_ca[:org_company_id] = @org_ca[:org_company_id][:id]
        
    # Edit function variables, in case of failed validations and we re-render :edit
    @person = OrgPerson.find_by(id: current_org_person.id) #Find the OrgPerson corresponding to org_person_id FK
    # Using the org_person_id find/create the record and assing the attributes to @contactInfo
    @contactInfo = OrgContact.find_or_initialize_by(org_person_id: current_org_person.id).attributes
    @contactInfo[:email] = current_org_person.email
    @person.org_contacts.build(@contactInfo) #Build the form using @contactInfo
    if !@org_ca[:org_company_id].nil?
        OrgPerson.update(current_org_person.id ,org_company_id: @org_ca[:org_company_id])
    end
    # Find contacts record or create them if necessary
    @contact = OrgContact.find_or_create_by(org_person_id: current_org_person.id)
        
    # Try to save it, if it saves, then redirect to the edit page with success
    if @contact.update_attributes(@org_ca) 
        # If this user also controls the information of the company (i.e. COO) then also update company email
        OrgContact.where(email: current_org_person.email).update_all(email: @org_ca["email"]) 
        # If there is a company, update the person record to reflect the company too.
        flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
        redirect_to edit_org_person_path(@person.id)
    else # Failed. Re-render the page as unsucessful
        render :edit
    end
    
end

private 
    def update_person_params
        params.require(:org_person).permit(org_contacts_attributes: [:address1, :address2,
        :city, {typ_countries: :id}, {typ_regions: :id}, {org_company: :id}, :postal_code, :email, 
        :business_number, :cell_number, :org_person_id, :avatar])
    end
```

Comment: You have shown us the generated error but we need to see the full stack trace so we can check what params have been passed into the controllers action.  You need to intialise `@org_ca` before it can be used. `@org_ca = OrgCa.new` but I don't know what the actual class is so that might not work. That is overly complex code, Can I humbly suggest you learn from AWDWR, google it.